# How to convert this regex Query in Oracle to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, regex

I am a beginner with regex query therefore I want to ask you how to convert this regex query in Oracle to SQL Server?

```
select * 
from Sales 
where regexp_like(productname,'^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]+$')
```

I convert it to this query:

```
select * 
from Sales 
where substr(productname, 1, 3) in ([A-Z])
```

Is that correct?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales
WHERE LEFT(productname, 3) LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]' -- three chars ([A-Z]{3})
  AND NOT RIGHT(productname, LEN(productname) - 3) LIKE '%[^0-9]%' -- only numbers after the first three chars
  AND NOT LEN(RIGHT(productname, LEN(productname) - 3)) = 0 -- at least one number
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f53fe21601dad8ab6c2f93620f3b870d)

Comment: previously, it worked too ( with `WHERE LEFT(productname, 3) LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]' 
  AND NOT RIGHT(productname, LEN(productname) - 3) LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` )

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - no because `ABC` would match without `AND NOT LEN(RIGHT(productname, LEN(productname) - 3)) = 0` too. But the original regex is `^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]+`. So the value have to be `ABC` and the fourth char should be a number.

Comment: thankyou very much Brosch, Can you please explain what does  '%[^0-9]%' mean?. i have read somewhere that '^' mean contrast. %[^0-9]% should mean: not a number??

Comment: this expression (`%[^0-9]%`) match all characters but not numbers (0 to 9) or a empty string.

Comment: So why did you wrote that: 'LIKE '%[^0-9]%' -- only numbers after the first three chars' ?. i am confusing.

Comment: The rule is the first three chars have to be A-Z. The second and third condition exclude all records with a not numeric char or a length of 0 (after the three chars at the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

Based on regexp `'^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]+$'`:

```
-- exactly 3 letters
-- at least one trailing digits
```

You could use `TRIM`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales
WHERE productname LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9]%'
  AND TRIM( '0123456789' FROM  productname) LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]';
      -- warning! expression is not SARGable
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6c388d207519da75dd816818cceac03f)**

Answer (score 0):

Think the most simple would be to use

```
WHERE 
   SUBSTRING(<column>, 1, 1) IN('A', 'B', 'C')
 AND
   SUBSTRING(<column>, 2, 1) IN('A', 'B', 'C')
 AND
   SUBSTRING(<column>, 2, 1) IN('A', 'B', 'C') 
 AND
   TRY_CONVERT(
        INT
        , SUBSTRING(<column>, 4, LEN(<column>))
   ) <> 0
```

as you don't really need regex to do this.

see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ea80fd77f887b363d0c63887b28d407a)